# Merge faster than Insert

Tags: sql-server, performance, insert, merge

Are there any advantages/disadvantages of making use of a `merge` over a `insert` function? Can an `insert` statement make use of the `OUTPUT'

Note: the `ON` clause for the `merge` is set to `1=0` (always insert)

```
Merge DeviceReading
    Using (
        --table here
    ) As [Source]
    On (1 = 0) -- Effectively Makes this an Insert as 1 Never Matches 0
    When Not Matched Then
        INSERT (
            [value1],
            [value2]
        ) VALUES (
            @value1,
            @value2
        ) OUTPUT Inserted.[value1], Inserted.[value2] Into @InsertIDTable;
```

Comment: Obligatory, please read this post on `MERGE`: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`MERGE` has more flexible `OUTPUT`. `OUTPUT` can refer to the merge source which is handy if you want the client to be able to match what it sent to what was actually inserted (e.g. `IDENTITY` values). `INSERT` can't do that (for no fundamental reasons; seems to be not implemented).

I can't think of any performance difference. The plans certainly look so similar that I can't make out a difference right now. If there was a major difference SQL Server could optimize one form to the other.

Comment: the `OUTPUT` clause can also be used in an `INSERT` statement.  Consequently, I see only disadvantages for using `MERGE` for unconditional inserts - much more code and unnecessary query plan operators, although probably not significant for performance.

Comment: @DanGuzman the OUTPUT clause cannot refer to the "merge source" in insert statements.

Comment: In the case of a value assigned by SQL Server, such as an `IDENTITY` or default constraint value, there is no original value provided for either `MERGE...NOT MATCHED` or `INSERT`.  One could add a `NULL` literal to the OUTPUT list for values not specified along with the values specified in the `VALUES` clause to get before/after values.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. If you use a table as the source for the insert...select you need to match each source row with the ID that was generated. But OUTPUT can't output source values. So it's not possible in general to do that matching. With MERGE you can have a source column that contains some key that can be used to identify rows.

Answer (score 1):

After thinking about this, I decided to answer instead of comment to provide more detailed information.

Yes, an INSERT statement can use an OUTPUT clause. It can be specified before the VALUES clause. See the SQL Server Books Online (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx) for the authoritative T-SQL reference

I suggest you avoid `MERGE` for unconditional inserts in production code.  It provides no additional functionality, requires less codes, and is easier to maintain.  Comparing the execution plans of a `MERGE` versus `INSERT`, the `MERGE plan incudes additional scalar operators for the extra constants.  I wouldn't expect a significant execution time difference but compilation time might be a slightly higher.

Below are functionally identical examples of these two techniques.

```
DECLARE @value1 varchar(10)
  , @value2 int;
DECLARE @test table ( col1 char(8000), col2 int );
MERGE test
USING
    ( SELECT    1 x
    ) AS [Source]
ON ( 1 = 0 ) -- Effectively Makes this an Insert as 1 Never Matches 0
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT ( [col1], [col2] )
    VALUES ( @value1, @value2 )
OUTPUT
    Inserted.[col1]
  , Inserted.[col2]
    INTO @test;
GO
DECLARE @value1 varchar(10)
  , @value2 int;
DECLARE @test table ( col1 char(8000), col2 int );
INSERT  INTO dbo.test
        ( [col1], [col2] )
OUTPUT  Inserted.[col1], Inserted.[col2]
        INTO @test
VALUES  ( @value1, @value2 );
GO
```

[image]

Comment: You can do things with the output clause in merge that you can not do with insert. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5365629/using-merge-output-to-get-mapping-between-source-id-and-target-id